# How to bring the REMOTE ID of a commerce payment into the checkout completion page?

Tags: commerce, webforms

We're running on Drupal 7.72 and using Commerce and Commerce Webform to take payments on the website.

We would like to display the REMOTE ID (seen below) on the checkout completion page. We are not able to find any tokens for this purpose readily available in the replacement patterns.

How would we go about trying to achieve this?

Apologies - I'm pretty new to using this module.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, because each order may have any number of payment transactions (meaning there is no strict 1:1 relationship), we cannot provide a simple token to make this available. You could create a custom Order token for the logic you know works on your site (e.g. [commerce-order:payment-id] that prints the remote ID of the first successful payment associated with the order). Otherwise you could customize the checkout completion page through a custom checkout pane, message text, etc.